# Localizar url de páginas web ya abiertas y ejecutar código

Tags: python, selenium, power-automate

Objetivo: **acortar el tiempo** de ejecución lo máximo posible
Acción que más tarda: *abrir Firefox* (3-4 segundos).
Solución planteada: tener la **página ya abierta** para acceder y **ejecutar mi código**.

Investigación: he mirado ***psutil*** para conseguir el pid de los eventos de firefox que estaban activos pero no he conseguido una . Después he mirado la librería ***mechanize*** que tenia bastante buena pinta pero me daba error en la tercera línea de código ‍♂️.
**¿Sabéis alguna manera de conseguir lo que quiero?**

El programa que quiero mejorar obtiene el nombre, el precio y más estadísticas de la página de futbin, la cual es hija del famoso juego **FIFA 24**.
**Os dejo el código del programa que quiero mejorar aquí:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os, time

player_name = str(input('Nombre del jugador: '))
url = 'https://www.futbin.com/players?page=1&search={}'.format(player_name)

fire_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
fire_options.add_argument('--headless')
fire_options.set_preference("permissions.default.image", 0)
fire_options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.serviceworker.enabled", False)
fire_options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
fire_options.set_preference("browser.tabs.animate", False)

start = time.time()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=fire_options)
driver.get(url)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)

players = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="repTb"]/tbody/tr')
os.system('cls')

print('{:<5}{:<30}{:<10}{:<20}{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}'.format('POS', 'JUGADOR', 'RATE', 'PRECIO', 'PAC', 'SHO', 'PAS', 'DRI', 'DEF', 'PHY'))
for player in players:
    if player.get_attribute('class').startswith('player'):
        try:
            jugador = players.index(player)+1
            posicion = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="repTb"]/tbody/tr[{jugador}]/td[4]/div[1]')
            nombre = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'#repTb > tbody > tr:nth-child({jugador+1}) > td.table-row-text.row > div.d-inline.pt-2.pl-3 > div:nth-child(1) > a')
            valoracion = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/div[9]/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[{jugador}]/td[3]/span')
            
            precio = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="repTb"]/tbody/tr[{jugador}]/td[6]/span')

            PAC = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="repTb"]/tbody/tr[{jugador}]/td[10]/span')
            SHO = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="repTb"]/tbody/tr[{jugador}]/td[11]/span')
            PAS = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="repTb"]/tbody/tr[{jugador}]/td[12]/span')
            DRI = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="repTb"]/tbody/tr[{jugador}]/td[13]/span')
            DEF = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="repTb"]/tbody/tr[{jugador}]/td[14]/span')
            PHY = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="repTb"]/tbody/tr[{jugador}]/td[15]/span')

            print('{:<5}{:<30}{:<10}{:<20}{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}{:<5}'.format(posicion.text, nombre.text, valoracion.text, precio.text, PAC.text, SHO.text, PAS.text, DRI.text, DEF.text, PHY.text))
        except: # A partir de una cantidad de jugadores suele dar error, así que lo paro y fuera problema
            break

end = time.time()
print(f'Tiempo total: {end-start}')
```

Comment: Escribiste mucho palabras. Remove todo información que no es relacionada con tu problema, probablemente, despues, alguien vas a audarte.

Comment: Hecho!! Muchas gracias por el consejo

Comment: Esta es regla básico en stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solución planteada: tener la página ya abierta para acceder y ejecutar mi código.

Normalmente, cuando gente quiere obtener mucha informacíon u obetenerlo periodicamente, usan un navegador el cual está abierto y espera para nueva conexión.
Entonces, no necesitas esperar para crear un nuevo navegador cada vez.

**Puedes usar `docker container` con firefox:**

```
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#quick-start
```

**Cuando, un `docker container` trabaja, puedes conectarlo:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
...
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
    command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
)
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Greg, ya lo he conseguido